# Why changes to /etc/limits don't work on an embedded system

Tags: linux, ulimit

I am trying to provide support for core dump on my ARM based target. I have read about both `/etc/limits` and `/etc/security/limits.conf`. My target file system doesn't have the latter one on to it. So I have made below changes to `/etc/limits`

```
root C100000
```

After adding this line to `/etc/limits` was expecting the generation of core file but `ulimit -a` shows me

```
core file size (blocks, -c) 0
```

Why these changes into `/etc/limits` does not at all reflecting.

Now what should I have to do?

Do I have to add `/etc/security/limits.conf` to my filesystem?

I am not looking at option of using `setrlimit()`.

Comment: Why can't you use `ulimit -c unlimited` or similar variation of the `ulimit` command to enable core dumps?

Comment: `/etc/security/limits.conf` is read by PAM and `/etc/limits` is read by the shadow login suite; both apply to logged-in users and are installed on most non-embedded system. There's no point in creating configuration files for software that isn't present. Is your userland BusyBox? Or something else?

Comment: @Gilles our /etc/limits are definately coming from Shadow package,I am not sure my userland is Busybox or something else ,I do I check it??

Comment: Just because it is ARM doesn't make it embedded.  IMHO, if you have a file system and an etc directory.. it isn't "embedded".. it's just a Linux box running an ARM proc.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your system you might also have to edit `/etc/pam.d/common-session*` and add

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

And of course you have to start a new session for your changes to apply.

Comment: Do not have pam.d on my file system

Comment: Then I guess on a stripped down system you might have to fall back to `setrlimit()`.

Answer (score 0):

For creating core dump add following command to `/etc/profile`

`ulimit -c 10000`

This command set the size limit of core files to 10000 bytes (You can change it to unlimited). Then execute `/etc/profile/` again with `source /etc/profile` or `. /etc/profile`

Comment: We can't add /etc/profile file since if we  change /etc/profille then This will only take affect for program launched from a login shell, not for processes/services started by systemd. /etc/limits would the the proper location for settings these defaults